# Multiple Parameter passing in setTimeOut function throws Uncaught ReferenceError: method is not defined (anonymous function)?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, settimeout

I have a function `A()` which calls function `B(x, y);` which again calls `C(p,q);`

`A() --> B(x,y) -->C (p,q)`

```
function A() {
    B(x,y)
}
```

`B()` Processes JSONStore to extract data relevant for function `C`, Before JSONStore data extraction ends script makes a call for func `C(p,q)` so to avoid it I used setTimeOut with a 1 second delay.

```
function B(x,y) {
    if(p===undefined || q===undefined) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            C(p,q); 
        }, 1000);
    }    
}
```

But I am getting error as Uncaught ReferenceError: method is not defined `M979:192 C VM979:192 (anonymous function)`

```
function C(p,q) {
    .........
}
```

I have read many blogs related to setTimeOut and discovered this way to do it.

My code:

```
function Submit_Data() {    
    var ChatWindow_Height = 650;
    var ChatWindow_Width = 570;

    window.open("Live Chat", "chat", "height=" + ChatWindow_Height + ", width = " + ChatWindow_Width);

    post("https://xyz/abc/StartChat.aspx", "post");
}

var regUserName,regUserMobile;

function post(path, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    var collectionName = 'Registration';
    var JSONStoreCollections = {};
    JSONStoreCollections[collectionName] = {};
    JSONStoreCollections[collectionName].searchFields = {uName: 'string'};

    WL.JSONStore.init(JSONStoreCollections)
    .then(function () {
        WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).findAll().then(function (res) {    
            WL.Logger.info('Registration retrived is :', res);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

            console.log(res[0].json.userName+"  "+res[0].json.userMobile+" "+res[0].json.userPass+" "+res[0].json.userRePass);

            regUserName=res[0].json.userName;
            regUserMobile=res[0].json.userPass;

            console.log("For Chat Data 1 is "+regUserName+"  "+regUserMobile);
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            WL.Logger.error("Failed authentication "+err);
        });
    })
    .fail(function (err) {
        alert("Error is "+err);
    });
    if(regUserName===undefined || regUserMobile===undefined) {
        setTimeout(function()   {
            openChat(regUserName,regUserName); // Error Here
        }, 1000);
    }
}

function openChat(regUserName,regUserName) {
    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    form.setAttribute("target", "chat");

    var hiddenField1 = document.createElement("input");
    var hiddenField2 = document.createElement("input");
    var hiddenField3 = document.createElement("input"); 

    console.log("For Chat Data 3 is "+regUserName+"  "+regUserMobile);

    hiddenField1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField1.setAttribute("id", "vName");
    hiddenField1.setAttribute("name", "vName");
    hiddenField1.setAttribute("value", regUserName);

    hiddenField2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField2.setAttribute("id", "mobile");
    hiddenField2.setAttribute("name", "21512");
    hiddenField2.setAttribute("value", regUserMobile);

    hiddenField3.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField3.setAttribute("id", "state");
    hiddenField3.setAttribute("name", "21524");
    hiddenField3.setAttribute("value", "25");

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using setTimeout and not callback function?

Comment: Hm, it looks like `openChat` should be in scope. However, I don't understand why you use `setTimeout` instead of placing the call in the JSONstore callback?

Comment: Yeas true, that i should place openChat in JSONStore callback. Actually that was the first approach i did and i got same error Uncaught ReferenceError: method is not defined...

Comment: Either you have declared it different than you show us, or you are assigning `undefined` to `openChat` somewhere. Is this all of your code?

Comment: Bergi: As a workaround i commented out openChat function and placed its logic in JSON.get callback Success snippet. And if you have seen i am submitting a form as POST in  OpenChat method, so now i have placed that form submit code in my setTimeOut part. By this i am able to wait for 1 second to submit the form to server and mean while in that 1 second i am able to fetch data from JSONStore.get callback.

Comment: Also i made one function as call(a,b); which only alert parameter data and i called it from JSONStore.get callback and to my surprise its working fine. I am not getting why its messing up with openChat. i can go ahead with my workaround but as a programmer its a bad practice which i should avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are illogically placed:

```
if(regUserName===undefined || regUserMobile===undefined) {
    setTimeout(function()   {
        openChat(regUserName,regUserName); // Error Here
    }, 1000);
}
```

Just call `openChat` in the `JSONStore.get()` callback:

```
    regUserMobile=res[0].json.userPass;
    console.log("For Chat Data 1 is "+regUserName+"  "+regUserMobile);

    if(regUserName===undefined || regUserMobile===undefined) {
        openChat(regUserName,regUserName);
    }
})
```

You also might want to replace `===` with `!===`, there. I would imagine that was intended to be a check to see if the parameters are filled.

Comment: You are right, why i have used === instead of !=== , but even if i am using openChat in JSONStore.get() i am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: method is not defined"

Comment: The appraoch you asked me that is to call openChat() inside a callback  of JSONStore.get(). I cut pasted  if(regUserName===undefined || regUserMobile===undefined) {
        openChat(regUserName,regUserName);
    }  inside JSONStore.get() callback

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and i got the same error as you has mentioned, i have tweeked the code and now its working with this code just modify the URL link as per what you want.

```
function Submit_Data()
{   
    var ChatWindow_Height = 650;
    var ChatWindow_Width = 570;
    window.open("VodaFone Live Chat", "chat", "height=" + ChatWindow_Height + ", width = " + ChatWindow_Width);
    post("https://xyz/abc/StartChat.aspx", "post");
}

var regUserName,regUserMobile;
function post(path, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    form.setAttribute("target", "chat");

    var hiddenField1 = document.createElement("input");
    var hiddenField2 = document.createElement("input");
    var hiddenField3 = document.createElement("input"); 

    var collectionName = 'Registration';
    var JSONStoreCollections = {};
    JSONStoreCollections[collectionName] = {};
    JSONStoreCollections[collectionName].searchFields = {uName: 'string'};
    WL.JSONStore.init(JSONStoreCollections) 

    .then(function () 
            {
        WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).findAll().then(function (res) 
                {   
            WL.Logger.info('Registration retrived is :', res);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

            console.log(res[0].json.userName+"  "+res[0].json.userMobile+" "+res[0].json.userPass+" "+res[0].json.userRePass);

            regUserName=res[0].json.userName;
            regUserMobile=res[0].json.userMobile;

            hiddenField1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField1.setAttribute("id", "vName");
            hiddenField1.setAttribute("name", "vName");
            hiddenField1.setAttribute("value", regUserName);

            hiddenField2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField2.setAttribute("id", "mobile");
            hiddenField2.setAttribute("name", "21512");
            hiddenField2.setAttribute("value", regUserMobile);

            hiddenField3.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField3.setAttribute("id", "state");
            hiddenField3.setAttribute("name", "21524");
            hiddenField3.setAttribute("value", "25");


            console.log("For Chat Data 1 is "+regUserName+"  "+regUserMobile);

                })
                .fail(function (err) 
                        {
                    WL.Logger.error("Failed authentication "+err);
                        });
            })
            .fail(function (err) 
                    {
                alert("Error is "+err);
                    });

    if(regUserName===undefined || regUserMobile===undefined)
    {
        setTimeout(function()   {
            form.appendChild(hiddenField1);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField2);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField3);

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();

                }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I know this is different way and probably not advicable but that is how i fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

I tired this piece and its working correctly:

```
function A() {
    B(1, 2)
}

function B(x,y) {
    if(true) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            C(3,4); 
        }, 1000);
    }    
}

function C(p,q) {
    alert('in c')
}

A()
```

Comment: Jyoti: Simple approach works no doubt but my condition is in which i am using setTimeOut is different.

Comment: I tried your code also just commenting new lines in fucntion post() and things are working fine.

Comment: Starting from                                                             var collectionName = 'Registration';                                           to                                                                                     alert("Error is "+err);
    });

Comment: Hehehe... Thats main trick... You didnot understood question properly... The code you commented is IBM worklight snippet to extract data which is time consuming and due to aynchronous nature java script does not wait for extraction and move on for furthur code execution. So i had to use setTimeOut stating "Till time my JSONStore doesnot get extracted please wait for data from JSONStore" .. Just due to this someone down voted your answer... Your Soln is right but it doesnot fit in this context

Comment: I think asynchronous nature should not have impact on syntax.

Comment: While extracting data from JSONStore doc it consumes few milli second, which is actually causing the problem. But I understood that your point is relevant so i have up voted your answer.